# Relação entre colunas da mesma tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, join

Estou resolvendo um código onde tenho uma tabela com formas de pagamento. Dentro da tabela tenho muitos dados, mas minha dificuldade está em uma relação entre 3 colunas:

Tenho as colunas com **ID_Pagamento**, **ID_Local**, **Nome** e **ID_Pagamento_Master**. Preciso relacionar a coluna **ID_Pagamento_Master** com a coluna **ID_Pagamento**, retornando o **ID_Local** ao invés do **ID_Pagamento_Master**

Segue um exemplo da tabela apenas com os dados em questão:

```
ID_Pagamento| ID_Local | Nome | ID_Pagamento_Master
01AA , 01 , CartãoCrédito   , NULL
01AB , 02 , CartãoDébito    , NULL
01AC , 03 , PIX             , NULL
01AD , 04 , CC_Master       , 01AA
01AE , 05 , CC_Visa         , 01AA
01AF , 06 , CD_Master       , 01AB
01AG , 07 , CD_Visa         , 01AB
01AH , 08 , BankX           , 01AC
```

Pensei nessa resolução, mas não funcionou como esperado:

```
select tp.ID_Pagamento
, tp.ID_Local
, tp.Nome
, tp2.Id_Local AS ID_Pagamento_Master

from dbo.TipoPagamento tp

    left join TipoPagamento tp2 on tp2.ID_Pagamento_Master = tp.ID_Pagamento

where tp.ID_Empresa = 75
```

Porém a consulta retorna um resultado com valores repetidos e não vincula as tabelas.
O resultado esperado seria algo como isso:

```
ID_Pagamento| ID_Local | Nome | ID_Pagamento_Master
01AA , 01 , CartãoCrédito   , NULL
01AB , 02 , CartãoDébito    , NULL
01AC , 03 , PIX             , NULL
01AD , 04 , CC_Master       , 01
01AE , 05 , CC_Visa         , 01
01AF , 06 , CD_Master       , 02
01AG , 07 , CD_Visa         , 02
01AH , 08 , BankX           , 03
```

Os dados não podem ser alterados nem criadas tabelas temporárias

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: CTE Recursiva creio , https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/

Comment: Sua query parece correta, mas pressupõe que a coluna ID_Pagamento seja a PK da tabela.

Comment: Como ficou o resultado? na pergunta temos apenas o resultado esperado.